# How to set CORS in Cloudflare Workers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare

I'm a newbie in Cloudflare Workers.

How to set CORS in Cloudflare Workers?

```
  response = await cache.match(cacheKey);
  if (!response) {
    // handle fetch data and cache
  }
  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", event.request.headers.get("Origin"));
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    response
  }), {
    status: 200, headers: myHeaders
  });
```

Comment: Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to * or to the value contained in the Origin request header. Oh wait, your code already does that. Why do you need help?

Comment: This is not working, so I need help!

Comment: Have you tried setting a content-type header?

Comment: Yes, Of Course!
Any suggestion or code sample!
Thanks

Comment: @DuyHoangNguyen Have you got any solution to it?

Answer (score 18):

It's quite a pain actually. There is a [sample from Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/cors-header-proxy), but it can't be used directly. I finally worked it out recently, and put the detailed steps into a
[blog post](https://bartsolutions.github.io/2021/10/21/cloud-flare-cors-worker-setup/).

Here is the full code for the worker.

```js
// Reference: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/cors-header-proxy
const corsHeaders = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
}
function handleOptions (request) {
        // Make sure the necessary headers are present
        // for this to be a valid pre-flight request
        let headers = request.headers
        if (
                headers.get("Origin") !== null &&
                headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Method") !== null &&
                headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers") !== null
        ) {
                // Handle CORS pre-flight request.
                // If you want to check or reject the requested method + headers
                // you can do that here.
                let respHeaders = {
                        ...corsHeaders,
                        // Allow all future content Request headers to go back to browser
                        // such as Authorization (Bearer) or X-Client-Name-Version
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers"),
                }
                return new Response(null, {
                        headers: respHeaders,
                })
        }
        else {
                // Handle standard OPTIONS request.
                // If you want to allow other HTTP Methods, you can do that here.
                return new Response(null, {
                        headers: {
                                Allow: "GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS",
                        },
                })
        }
}
async function handleRequest (request) {
        let response
        if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
                response = handleOptions(request)
        }
        else {
                response = await fetch(request)
                response = new Response(response.body, response)
                response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        }
        return response
}
addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
        event.respondWith(
                handleRequest(event.request).catch(
                        (err) => new Response(err.stack, { status: 500 })
                )
        );
});
```

Comment: Hello! Do you known is there any way to not wait for `response = await fetch(request)` and relay response without actual download it to CF first and only response with result to a client after. In other words in php you can `readfile` or `file_get_contents`. Readfile will read the file directly into the output buffer, and file_get_contents will load the file into memory, when you echo the result the data is copied from memory to the output buffer effectively using 2 times the memory of readfile.

Answer (score 7):

This is the top Google result for 'cloudflare worker cors error'.

Here is a super simple way to set the correct headers.

You can call the Cloudflare function like this:

```
async function callCloudflareWorker(parameter) {
    const workerUrl = `https://name.account.workers.dev/`; // Replace  with your actual worker URL
    const response = await fetch(workerUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ parameter }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error calling Cloudflare Worker: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

This sends the server a request. Because it is coming from the browser, the server needs to send a thumbs up that, yes this is allowed.

Your Cloudflare worker would look like this:

```
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});

const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*', // What headers are allowed. * is wildcard. Instead of using '*', you can specify a list of specific headers that are allowed, such as: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization.
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST', // Allowed methods. Others could be GET, PUT, DELETE etc.
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // This is URLs that are allowed to access the server. * is the wildcard character meaning any URL can.
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return new Response("OK", {
      headers: corsHeaders
    });
  } else if (request.method === 'POST') {
    return doTheWork(request);
  } else if (request.method === 'GET') {
    return doTheWork(request);
  } else {
    return new Response("Method not allowed", {
      status: 405,
      headers: corsHeaders
    });
  }
}

async function doTheWork(request) {
  // Parse the request body to get the parameters
  const requestBody = await request.json();
  let parameter = requestBody.parameter;

  //do the work here
  let results = //What your worker does

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(results), {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      ...corsHeaders //uses the spread operator to include the CORS headers.
    }
  });
}
```

Notice how you had to include the headers on the response as well. It is like the browser and server are shaking hands that yes, this interaction is ok.

Of course using the * characters has issues, do some research to make sure you know what you are doing if you are setting and using cookies etc.

But this should help rookies like be able to use Cloudflare workers from the front end.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not set the Content-Type header. You should either set it with myHeaders.set() or use the original response headers instead of creating an empty headers object:

```
response = await cache.match(cacheKey);
if (!response) {
    // handle fetch data and cache
}
const myHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);
myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", event.request.headers.get("Origin"));
```

I'm also questioning why you are trying to use JSON.stringify on the response. I think what you want is something like this:

```
return new Response(response.body, {status: 200, headers: myHeaders});
```

Comment: Current code does not set the Content-Type header, but before post this question, I have configuration that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how got it working. I'm using [Itty Router](https://github.com/kwhitley/itty-router) but this should work the same for a normal worker as well.

```js
router.get("/data", async (request) => {
  const corsHeaders = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
  };
  if (request.method.toLowerCase() === "options") {
    return new Response("ok", {
      headers: corsHeaders,
    });
  }
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    return new Response(data, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
// don't forget this. You also need to send back the headers with the actual response
        ...corsHeaders,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {}

  return new Response(JSON.stringify([]), {
    headers: corsHeaders,
  });
});
```

Thanks to this Free Egghead video [Add CORS Headers to a Third Party API Response in a Workers API](https://egghead.io/lessons/cloudflare-add-cors-headers-to-a-third-party-api-response-in-a-workers-api)

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", is no longer allowed in modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

[Anurag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413644/8722289) got me 90% of the way there, thank you for that. I'm using `itty-router` as well, here's what I had to add.

I created a simple preflight middleware:

```
const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
};

export const withCorsPreflight = (request: Request) => {
  if (request.method.toLowerCase() === 'options') {
    return new Response('ok', {
      headers: corsHeaders,
    });
  }
};
```

I then added it to every route.

```
router.all('*', withCorsPreflight);
router.get('/api/another-route', handler);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", is no longer allowed in modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

add this,

```
const corsHeaders = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-worker-key,Content-Type,x-custom-metadata,Content-MD5,x-amz-meta-fileid,x-amz-meta-account_id,x-amz-meta-clientid,x-amz-meta-file_id,x-amz-meta-opportunity_id,x-amz-meta-client_id,x-amz-meta-webhook',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
    'Allow': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
};

export function addCORSHeaders(response: Response){
    const newResponse = new Response(response.body, {
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        headers: corsHeaders,
    });
    return newResponse;
};
```

consume like this

```
export function consumer(env: Env,request: Request,response: Response){
    //TODO: Code Here

    return addCORSHeaders(new Response(response.body)) ;
}
```