# How to set HTTP OPTIONS Method in Cloudflare only to allow GET and POST

Tags: dns, http-headers, cloudflare, http-method

I have Cloudflare free SSL enabled on a website and I need to change the HTTP OPTIONS Method to allow only GET and POST.

I've used this command in SSH to check what methods are available:

*curl -X OPTIONS https://example.com -I*

and the relevant result is:

```
...
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xxxx)
> OPTIONS / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
...
```

From "accept: */*" I understand that all methods are allowed and I would like to change this.

I have tried to edit the .htaccess file on the server and added

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(POST|GET)\ /.*\ HTTP/1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

and it didn't seem to work and I think it may be something I can fix in Cloudflare but have no clue how should I do this. Does anyone know if this can be done and can point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing a couple concepts with the way you phrase your question. There are many ways to *block* any HTTP methods besides GET / PUT (both with Cloudflare, or directly on your server with htaccess).

However, because you brought up the OPTIONS method, it sounds like you are wanting to broadcast which methods are available? In this case, you'll want to read up on the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' header -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Essentially this is what tells the browser (or client) after making an OPTIONS request, what methods are available for the given endpoint.

To use it, you can either add headers with htaccess or Cloudflare.

Comment: Yes, most likely I'm confusing a lot of things. Happy to hear that are more ways to do this.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to secure the website and I've found out that HTTP OPTIONS method  can be useful to an attacker.
So, I dug a little deeper, and it seems my htaccess rules may work but I need to allow Cloudflare to cache it or use Cloudflare Workers to set the rules that htaccess can't. I've found this, and I think I can use as a guideline:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486610/how-to-set-cors-in-cloudflare-workers
I'll check fi caching works then try Cloudflare Workers. Thanks